# How to use custom domain for ALB in front of ECS Fargate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-route53, aws-fargate, amazon-elb

I have a couple of ECS tasks running in Fargate behind an ALB. I want to use a custom domain for the ALB so I created a hosted zone and an A record that points to the ALB but when navigating to the record name I get the "This page isn't working error". Is it mandatory to register the domain via the Route 53 or any other registrar or is the hosted zone and record enough for it to work? We have other ALBs with custom domains and when I navigate to the url the site comes up just fine. Settings look like mine so I am not sure if those are using a different registrar, which my hunch says they do.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: There is an option to use public hosted zones with external Domain Name Providers. The only thing I think you missed, is that to update the NS record at the registrar, or the parent zone, to use Route 53 name servers

more info here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/migrate-dns-domain-in-use.html#migrate-dns-change-name-servers-with-provider

Answer (score 0):

> Is it mandatory to register the domain via the Route 53 or any other registrar or is the hosted zone and record enough for it to work?

The hosted zone is not enough for it to work. You absolutely have to register the domain with a domain registrar. You have to own the custom domain you are trying to use. You can use any registrar, not just Route53. You have to configure your Route53 hosted zone's NS records with the domain registrar before the hosted zone will work.

Comment: Ok cool thanks Mark. Always a big help!